# Should a C library offer ability to use custom memory allocators?

Tags: c, design-patterns, malloc

I see that some C libraries have [ability to specify custom memory allocators](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html#section-5.1) (`malloc`/`free` replacements).

- In what systems/environments/conditions is that useful? Isn't this feature just a leftover from MSDOS era or similar no-longer-relevant problems?

#### Background story:

I'm planning to make [pngquant](http://pngquant.org) a library that can be embedded in various software (from iOS apps to Apache modules). I'm using `malloc()`/`free()` and my own memory pools for small allocations. I use 2MB-50MB of memory in total. I use threads, but only need to alloc on the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any application where control over memory allocation is critical (for example my field, game development, or other real or near real time systems) the inability to control memory allocations in a library immediately disqualifies it from use.

Comment: What does your malloc do? Is it just performance? Can you limit mem fragmentation when other code controls allocations? Do you put limit on max mem usage? Would regular malloc/free be OK in non-realtime parts of the game (e.g. "Save screenshot to disk" feature)

Comment: Yes a combination of performance, fragmentation and knowing how much memory you consume. For debugging features it's usually fine to use malloc but this code is disabled in retail builds.

Comment: Would it be useful to allow separate allocators [or a second arg to custom malloc] defined for temporary buffers (used internally in the lib) and for long-lived data (returned to user)?

Answer (score 1):

Many malloc/free algorithms exist. The system malloc is sometimes not optimized for the task that the library is handling, so the caller might want to try a few different ones to optimize performance.

A few that come to mind are:

- [dlmalloc](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html)
- [jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/)
- [TCMalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html)

There are also Garbage Collection libraries such as the [Boehm Garbage Collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector) which are usable in C by calling the provided malloc/free replacements (even though free is then a dummy function call, kept for compatibility).

There are also many possible uses, for example one may write a debug malloc/free function that could trace memory allocations and liberations in the library, such as one that I wrote that uses SQLite to record statistics about how the memory is used (admittedly at the cost of performance, but it is a debugging situation).